# How to have useful errors in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm working on Xamarin and i have a real problem : i can't debug anything because when my application crash i never had informations about how and where.
The output log only send me useless messages like

Exception thrown at 0x0AE440F8 in MyApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

How am I supposed to know what is the problem ? And it like this for everything. I just have this error and nothing else. Where are errors ? How can i know where and why it crash because i can't fix an issue if i don't know what is the problem...

Thank you for any help

Comment: What platform is this on? Do you have debugging enabled for that App?

Comment: I'm targeting uwp, i think debugging is enabled i can see my Debug.WriteLine() and i have my output console in 'Debug' mode

Comment: Interesting. It does say Access Violation, so perhaps it is one of the harder crashes where there is no stack trace. If you throw your own exception, does that work?

Comment: If i htrow my own it works but never the others, all my exceptions since 2 month can't be everytime harders... And i think it's not a big crash (i 'm just converting string into int). This error is a parsexception. I think 'Violation access' is the default error throwed because i always have this one

Comment: I found a begining of a solution here
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9a6a3b90-ac44-4916-b893-a35654ab498a/visualstudio-2015-update-1-on-windows-10-1511th2-cannot-find-or-open-the-pdb-file?forum=vsdebug